# longjmp from a forked process

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, x86

Ok, here is what I want to achieve. I want the **threadRoutine** thread of the forked process to only start executing from a particular point as shown by the comment *//Thread of the forked process should start executing from here*. I use the same memory area for the stack of the original and forked **threadRoutine**. But I suspect that since the **threadRoutine** of the forked process does execute **longjmp** as I set **cp_thread** to 1, its stack starts to diverge from the **threadRoutine** of the original process and so it cannot jump where I intended.

How can I solve this problem, that is don't diverge the stacks of the original and **threadRoutine** of the forked process in the precence of **longjmp** for the forked process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

pthread_attr_t attr;
int cp_thread = 0;
static jmp_buf buf;
pthread_barrier_t bar;

void make_jmp_if_req()
{
    if ( cp_thread )
        longjmp( buf, 1 );
}

void *threadRoutine(void *threadMsg)
{
    size_t myStackSize;
    void *stackAddr;

    make_jmp_if_req();

    printf("%d: TR:{stackAddr pointer = %lx, @threadRoutine = %lx}\n", 
           getpid(), stackAddr, threadRoutine );
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attr,&stackAddr,&myStackSize);

    setjmp( buf );
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);

    printf("%d: TR:stack address %p\n", getpid(), stackAddr);
    printf("%d: TR:stack size is %x\n", getpid(), myStackSize);
    //printf("%d\n",*((int *)stackAddr)); // <--------------------Causing segmentation fault..
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t stacksize;
    void *stackAddr;
    int rc;
    size_t i;
    pthread_t thread;
    pid_t pid;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    // So that setjmp in the threadRoutine of the orignal process is called before             
    //  longjmp from threadRoutine of the forked process.
    pthread_barrier_init(&bar, NULL, 2);

    stacksize = 0xC00000; //12582912;
    stackAddr = malloc(stacksize);
    printf("Main:{stackAddr = %lx}\n", stackAddr );
    pthread_attr_setstack(&attr,stackAddr, stacksize);
    pthread_attr_getstack(&attr,&stackAddr, &stacksize);
    printf("Main:stack address %p\n",stackAddr);
    printf("Main:stack size is %x\n",stacksize);

    rc = pthread_create( &thread, &attr, threadRoutine, (void*)0 );
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);

    switch(pid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
      printf("fork failed");
      break;
    case 0: // Child
      printf( "Child pid() = %d\n", getpid() );
      cp_thread = 1;
      rc = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, threadRoutine,(void *)0);
      break;
    default:// Leader
      printf( "Parent pid() = %d\n", getpid() );
      //rc = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, threadRoutine,(void *)0);
    }

    if(rc) 
    {
      printf("ERROR:return code from pthread_create %d\n",rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: When you say, "So, please do not say to not use this and do things differently," you are asking people to not answer your question.  If you want a useful answer, show us what it is you're really trying to do rather than presenting "an exercise".

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to the fact that `fork()` don't reproduce the threads (existing in the parent process which calls fork) in the child process. After a fork() only a single thread exist in the child process.

Also, you should **always call `setjmp` before `longjmp`** so your threadRoutine is incorrect. And of course, you should not *longjmp* into *another* thread.

Don't use threads with *fork* without enormous precautions. Learn more about `pthread_atfork`.

And I don't really understand why you want to do all this. I still believe you should not code that way (or you are not enough explaining why you want to do that, and what for).

Regards.

Comment: Yes I know, and this is why I am doing this exercise. Seeing if its possible to resurrect dead threads in a forked process. You are right, setjmp should not be called before longjmp, maybe I should put a barrier after the first pthread_create and after doing setjmp from the original thread. What I'm trying to do here is to have the same stack for the original thread and the one in the forked process and CPU state, that I'm trying to save with setjmp/longjmp.

Comment: Have put the barriers now, so that setjmp of threadRoutine of original process is called before longjmp from threadRoutine of forked process.

Comment: Resurrecting threads using this mechanism is completely undefined. The setjmp/longjmp is only defined for use within the same thread, and does not save enough state to be used across threads. If you're trying to recreate threads that were running in the parent process in a sub-process after forking, then you should design it using coroutines, where you force all the threads to 'join' before forking and then resume them from the known state in the subprocess. Generally trying to implement forkall for a multi-threaded process on an OS that doesn't support it is akin to process suspend/resume

Comment: Petesh, yeah that is exactly what I was trying. Say if I have 4 threads, what I would like to do is to fork at barrier point. And through a combination of setjmp/longjmp and using the same stacks for the threads in original and forked process, try to do that. You said to resume them from the known state. OK, but how can I do that, since the threads are dead in the forked process. What I was doing is to call pthread_create against the same stack area use by the dead thread. Infact, I saw that stack remains intact. setjmp additionaly gives things such as stack pointer, instruction pointer etc.